# Fresh Debian 11 netinstall fails:"apt-get install "task-gnome-desktop" unable to locate package

Tags: debian

I mistakenly installed a netinstall-iso and struggeled to get it connected to WiFi. Now as it is connected and after i Performer "apt-get Upgrade && apt-get Update" it doesnt find task-xfce-desktop. (apt-get install task-xfce-desktop -y   = E: Unable to locate package) Furthermore it also doesnt find "task-gnome-desktop" (i am Not bounded to a specific GUI). Someone Knows why i cant find a Desktop GUI package?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt update`?

Comment: Yes i did. See the reworked question

Comment: Are you repositories set correctly ?

Comment: I have Not manipulated the repositories and the official debian11 Page describes "task-gnome-desktop" as manually installable. Is it a Problem with the netinstall-iso?

Comment: Can you maybe add to your question the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list? Please enclose them in the curly brackets `{}` to keep the formatting.

Comment: deb http://security.debian.org/Debian-Security bullseye-security main + deb-src  http://security.debian.org/Debian-Security bullseye-security main. No curly brackets found.  Additional Infos: #This system was installed using small removable Media. The Matching "deb CD-ROM" was disabled at the end of the Installation process. For Information about how to configure apt package sources, See the sources.list(5) manual

Answer (score 1):

Okay i got it. The minimal-installer has (for this Case) missing dependencies in /etc/apt/sources.list.

I Had to add:

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main

I gathered this information here: https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList

Depending on your system "non-free" and "contribut" (could) must be added as attributes as well.